# how can i set session cookie value without server name?

Tags: java, jsp, session, jsessionid

In java, `JSESSIONID` has a value with following format:

> JSESSIONID=UvDBSG6PjxsVMyDo0x5NDkM9ou`.server_name`

But, I want to use `JSESSIONID` value without server name like with this format.

> JSESSIONID=UvDBSG6PjxsVMyDo0x5NDkM9ou

So, I had extended `HttpSession` and `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for create `JSESSIONID` that like with above mentioned format.

It is responded correctly at first time. But, if client(browser) try access to a resource(css, img, js and other web resource file. except servlet request), server response the `JSESSIONID` that include `server name` like with origin format.

Why this situation is happened?

Is it possible to intercept request that access to resource?
Or is it possible to configure `JSESSIONID` without `server name`?

Comment: please clarify what kind of resources you do mean.

Comment: The resource is css, img, js and other web resource file